# Email Application That stores Messages as Single Files

Tags: thunderbird, email

Are there any applications (like Thunderbird) that handle emails for Ubuntu that store messages as single files?

I've added my Thunderbird folder to MEGA for syncing, but it includes files up to about 650MB, which are updated several times a day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand that you are referring to `mbox` and `Maildir` email storage format.
Thunderbird uses `mbox` format. This means that stores entire `Inbox` mail directory in a single system file. When using cloud storage, this will result to extensive traffic.

You need to find an email client which uses `Maildir` format.

In ubuntu most popular email clients are [evolution](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Evolution) and [Kmail](https://userbase.kde.org/KMail). Both of them support `Maildir`. Of course both of them included in ubuntu's repositories.

For further investigation, there is an extensive list in wikipedia with several email clients. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_email_clients#Database.2C_folders_and_customization

Refer to "Message file format" column.

Answer (score 2):

A small test shows that [Sylpheed](http://sylpheed.sraoss.jp/en/) (in the repositories) stores emails as single files in `~/Mail`.  Or, as it sais [here](http://sylpheed.sraoss.jp/doc/faq/en/sylpheed-faq-1.html#d0e197):

*The MH format has less possibility of losing mails on failures since one file corresponds to one mail.*

Sylpheed is the default email application in Lubuntu.

`~/Mail/sent`

[image]

`~/Mail/inbox`

[image]